# cocos2dx c++ android Not rendering a MenuItemImage

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, render

Hey im using cocos2dx c++ and encountered a problem,
This is my initalization for the MenuItemImage

```
/*Create Menu*/
auto options_btn = MenuItemImage::create(
    "MenuAssets/Buttons/Options_UP.png",
    "MenuAssets/Buttons/Options_Down.png",
    CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenu::menuCloseCallback, this));

auto play_btn = MenuItemImage::create(
    "MenuAssets/Buttons/Play_UP.png",
    "MenuAssets/Buttons/Play_Down.png",
    CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenu::menuCloseCallback, this));

auto achivement_btn = MenuItemImage::create(
    "MenuAssets/Buttons/Achivements_Up.png",
    "MenuAssets/Buttons/Achivements_Down.png",
    CC_CALLBACK_1(MainMenu::menuCloseCallback, this));
```

Now The positioning

```
play_btn->setScale(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
play_btn->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x+ visibleSize.width / 2,
    origin.y  + visibleSize.height/ 2));

options_btn->setScale(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
options_btn->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width / 2 + 150,
    origin.y + 100 + options_btn->getContentSize().height / 2));

achivement_btn->setScale(CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR());
achivement_btn->setPosition(Vec2(origin.x + visibleSize.width / 2 - 150,
    origin.y + 100 + achivement_btn->getContentSize().height / 2));
```

Initalizatino of menu Object

```
auto menu = Menu::create(options_btn, achivement_btn, play_btn, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
this->addChild(menu, 1);
```

The problem i encountered is on Win32 it's works fines
but in android it draws only the Achievments button for some reason
The size of the images are: Play: 175x175,
Options and Achievments are 75x75
It looks like it ignores loading the play and option images because if i set another image location for the achievment button  it doesn't render it aswell
what could cause this problem? what do i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it up
Seems llike anroid is case-sensitive while Windows isn't
Changing the name to the sensitive fixed this problem